# Understanding Partial derivative - how they work in this example

Tags: proof-explanation, differential-operators

Can someone please help me in understanding why the following equation is true?

$[(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r})^2+ r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}] = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = (\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r)^2$

I understand how $(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r})^2 = r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} + r^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}$, however, for the previous equation I am at a lost. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How did you get the second one.

Comment: The simplest way to verify is to apply it to a function, i.e. (r d/dr)^2 f(r).

Comment: Apply it on f(r)/r and rf(r).